# how to log generated sql executed by JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

when executing JOOQ queries, what is the easiest way to log the generated SQL being executed to the log

Comment: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/sql-execution/logging/

Comment: the solution in there says to put 'DEBUG' on the root logger, which in a large program would make all libraries output all sorts of info.

Comment: Maybe the better approach is to log queries on database layer depending on RDBMS: extended events/audit/profiler?

Comment: that adds a whole lot of complication than just turning on logging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, this is documented in the manual: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/logging/.

So you don't have to enable `DEBUG` logging on the root logger, you can do it only on the `org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener` logger, which does all the SQL logging in jOOQ.

Comment: i wish the `org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener` part was documented.

Comment: Agreed. I filed an enhancement request for this.